# mod-rewrite condition is not working properly in IIS6

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, iis-6

Additional questions for mod-rewrite module coded by [Helicon](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/) for IIS6.  First condition for redirecting IP addresses works as expected.  However, I have also added a second rewrite condition that does not appear to be working correctly.  Here is my .htaccess file (I know that the mod-rewrite module is typically included within Apache servers, but for IIS6, a company called [Helicon](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/) coded their own module that emulates what Apache does).  I have asked the vendor for comment, and they don't know why it does not work, it should be.  Here is my .htaccess file (note that the there are two RewriteCond and RewriteRules in the same file--the ip filter works, but the filter on the agent does not):

**IP, REMOTE_ADDR CONDITION WORKS**

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (\b89\.242\.(?!36)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\b88\.78\.30\.\d{1,3}|etc...)
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.aspdnsf.com/CASP_BotCatch.aspx\?htaccess=1&agentblock=0&ipblock=1 [I,RP]
```

**AGENT, User-Agent: CONDITION DOES NOT WORK**

```
RewriteCond User-Agent: .*Java.*
RewriteRule (.*) http\://www.aspdnsf.com/CASP_BotCatch.aspx\?htaccess=1&agentblock=1&ipblock=0 [I,RP]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Flavor of regex is perl

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check the value of the user-agent header sent by the browser, then try changing your second set of rules to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Java
RewriteRule .* http\://www.aspdnsf.com/CASP_BotCatch.aspx\?htaccess=1&agentblock=1&ipblock=0 [I,RP]
```

The modified RewriteCond directive should only match if the string "Java" appears in the value of the HTTP_USER_AGENT server variable.

Comment: I have tried this syntax as well.  Can't I use more than one condition???  Is there a difference between .*Java.* and just using the characters Java?  Perl regex interprets dot as any charater, any number of times then literal J, literal a, v, a then any character any number of times.  I think either way will work but I think the real problem is that it is not reading the second condition.  I have not tested Java by itself.

Comment: Oh, are you trying to execute the RewriteRule only if the user-agent contains Java AND the remote address matches your list?

Comment: No i want both conditions.  The rewrite rule has a paramater that tells which condition was used.

Comment: Which condition is more important? If Java is found, should that rule take precedence over the IP-address match, or vice versa?

Comment: This turned out to be a simple caching problem.  Thanks Arkanon